# SSRS - Get current tablix iteration index

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report which contains a tablix. Within this tablix I have a subreport that is called at each tablix iteration.
I would like to obtain the current index of the tablix iteration inside the subreport. I have passed a subreport parameter using below expression:

=RowNumber("dataset")

dataset is the one assigned to the tablix in the report. In my concret case, this expression is not working.

Any other way to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

Is your tablix grouping the data from your dataset?  If so, can you do that grouping/aggregation in your SQL and return only the final dataset in the format the tablix will be displaying it?

If you can manage that, you can simply add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <column names>) as RowNum` and pass that through as `=Fields!RowNum.Value` to your subreport.